# Selenium Firefox always error

Tags: selenium

Selenium plugin on firefox always gives a error saying 
[error] current test case not found

[image]

Do anyone know how to solve this?

Comment: Please add more info to your question; for e.g.: what have you tried to figure out where you are going wrong?

Comment: Fixed it. it was due to firefox was not restarted correctly by the plugin. after restart it worked.

Comment: okay. then in that case, to keep this website clean, please either delete your question or answer your own question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed it. it was due to firefox was not restarted correctly by the plugin. after restart it worked.